# HQL Equivalent of SQL Contains

Tags: sql, hql, contains

I'm trying to write an HQL query to select objects which contain an object in a child collection.

Example:

**Contest Object**

```
ContestID  
ContestName  
RequiredCountries -> one to many collection of Country objects
```

**Country Object**

```
CountryCode  
CountryName
```

The sql equivalent of what i want:

```
SELECT * FROM CONTEST C  
WHERE C.CONTESTID IN(SELECT CONTESTID FROM CONTEST_COUNTRY CC INNER JOIN COUNTRY CTRY ON   
CC.COUNTRYCODE = CTRY.COUNTRYCODE WHERE COUNTRYCODE='USA')
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM CONTEST C  
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT CONTESTID FROM CONTEST_COUNTRY CC INNER JOIN COUNTRY CTRY ON 
CC.COUNTRYCODE = CTRY.COUNTRYCODE WHERE COUNTRYCODE='USA' AND CC.CONTESTID=C.CONTESTID)
```

I have this hql, which works, but seems like not a good solution-

```
from Contest C  
where (from Country where CountryCode = :CountryCode) =  some elements(C.RequiredCountries)
```

I also consider joining with Country, but since I don't have an object class to represent the relationship, I wasn't sure how to join in HQL.

Anyone have any ideas or suggestions?  This should be easy.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

try this:

```
from Contest Ct, Country Cr
where Cr.CountryCode = :CountryCode 
    and Cr.Country in elements(Ct.RequiredCountries)
```

[Related article](http://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/nhibernate/1.2/reference/en/html/queryhql.html)

Comment: Exactly what i needed, creates an IN statement in SQL

Answer (score 8):

The previous one will work (at least it works for me --- I'm using hibernate), but the 'proper way' is the 'member of' operator... like this:

```
select ...
from Contest Ct, Country Cr
where Cr.CountryCode = :CountryCode
  and Cr.Country member of Ct.RequiredCountries
```

(see http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbuf.html#bnbvk)

The elements() is HQL extension, I think. I think it's better to use the standard (JPQL) whenever possible.